# Can the pyrophoric tendencies of a pyrophoric substance be suppressed in a pressurized environment?

Tags: combustion, temperature, pressure

It's common knowledge that the pressure of an environment influences many properties of a substance, like the melting point, boiling point, or triple point. Pyrophoric substances ignite spontaneously at temperatures below $\pu{55^\circ C}$, like caesium for example.

I wish to ask if the tendency for pyrophoric substances to ignite is influenced at all by pressure? Obviously, these substances would not spontaneously ignite in a vacuum, but would their ignition temperature change and/or be dependent on the pressure of their environment? Is there a pressure apart from a vacuum that could cause the substance to lost its pyrophoric properties?

Comment: How do you imagine changing triple point? Are you only asking about elements and phase changes or pressure induced reactions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the pyrophoric substance, there can be differeing effects from changing air pressure. Strange as it may seem, sometimes combustion is *slowed* at very high pressure. For example, [ethane, which reacts explosively with oxygen at STP, oxidizes slowly in a series of steps at ~100 atmospheres (~10<sup>7</sup> Pascals).](https://www.jstor.org/stable/96000?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

That said, it depends on the substances involved, pressure and presence of catalysts or other substances. [Aluminum in a ball mill produces pyrophoric dust, but adding graphite during milling suppresses ignition.](http://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=93659.0)